# My cat has become distant and scared of everything

Tags: cats

Ever since i have taken in a stray my pet cat has become very distant and is scared of eveyrthing even my touch everytime I try to pet her she runs away and most of the time is scared of everything even my slippers. What do i do?

Comment: can you please add a bit more information to your question,the age of the cats? spayed/neutered? do your cats live indoor only or indoor and outdoor?

Comment: Additionally to @trondhansen's questions, how did you introduce the cats? Did you have the stray vetted before you exposed them to one another? What gender is your cat? What gender is the stray? There's a lot of key information missing here.